# How do you modify a QListWidgetItem class in Pyside6?

Tags: qlistwidget, pyside6, qlistwidgetitem

In my program,I want to create a list (QListWidget) with modified list items (inherit QListWidgetItem) using Pyside6. The following code wants to modify the items so that they can show two images. But it is just an example, it is more how you create modified list in general that I want to know how to make.

My idea is:

1. To create a class that inherits QListWidgetItem.
2. In that class to create the layout with whatever widgets you want the listItem to have.
3. Create a Widget that wraps this list item and then set that as the Item to be shown.

My code is just showing a blank MainWindow where I can highlight two rows meaning the list is created and the items is added, just not visible. "image1.jpg" and "image2.jpg" are just arbitrary.

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from mainWindow import MainWindow
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QListWidget, QListWidgetItem, QLabel, QWidget, QStyledItemDelegate
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Rescue Creator")
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.listWidget = QListWidget()

        item1 = listWidgetItem()
        item2 = listWidgetItem()

        self.listWidget.addItem(item1)
        self.listWidget.addItem(item2)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.listWidget)

class listWidgetItem(QListWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.imageLabel1 = QLabel()
        self.imageLabel2 = QLabel()
        self.image1 = QPixmap("image1.jpg")
        self.image2 = QPixmap("image2.jpg")
        self.imageLabel1.setPixmap(self.image1)
        self.imageLabel2.setPixmap(self.image2)
        self.listLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.listLayout.addWidget(self.imageLabel)
        self.listLayout.addWidget(self.layerMaskLabel)

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.listLayout)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

I tried the code above, chatGPT said something about a method like `self.setLayout(self.listLayout)` in the end of listWidgetItemClass but that might be for Pyqt5 or something.

Comment: First of all, while AI is a wonderful technology, it's not yet ready to answer to such complex answers, unless it's been properly *trained*. And that is clear from the fact that ChatGPT clearly doesn't realize that QListWidgetItem is **not** a widget. If you want to show a widget in a QListView or its inherited QListWidget you must use `setIndexWidget` or `setItemWidget`. But that's not all: since you don't actually need any interaction, a *better* solution is to use a custom item delegate instead, which is just *slightly* more complex but will certainly improve performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From my experience, it is actually quite impressive but don't seem to differentiate between Pyqt and Pyside unfortunately. i will need interaction with the images in a later stage, select them etc, is still custom item delegate the way to go? There seem to be very few examples of this from what I have found.

Comment: That depends on what you *actually* want to do. PyQt and PySide are actually not that different: they fundamentally do the same thing (provide a Python binding to the C++ library): there are some slight differences you can only understand and realize with experience, and, most importantly, they cannot be used together (either use one or the other, **never** mix them). The interaction you're writing about is not very clear: if by "select them" you mean selecting their item in the list, that's one thing, if you mean accessing or editing their contents, that's another story.

Comment: More specifically, I want to create a "light" version of Photoshop. In this case, I want the list to display items that basically are the different images and their respective layer masks. So I want to be able to later on check which item that is selected and also if it is the image or layer mask to then be able to edit and update them. That is why I thought I create a class that inherit QListWidgetItem so that the list just simply can view that instead. But it seems that my logic is wrong here.

Comment: Then your better option is to create a custom *item delegate*, and (at least) override its [`paint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstyleditemdelegate.html#paint) function. I suggest you to do some research on these topics, but also take your time to carefully read the documentation about [Qt model/view programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html).

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will look more into delegates then.